# Frozen screen after login in to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, apt, xorg, screen, amd-graphics

I'm new to using linux distros so i have very limited knowledge on linux. couple of days ago i installed Ubuntu 18.04 and it worked perfectly fine at first. i installed the operating system and then installed most of the important softwares that was needed. while i was working it got frozen and i had to power off using the power button and ever since, i can log in to the desktop but is "freezed", like nothing happens expect the cursur moves around. i cant select anything, keyboard shortcuts dont work, nothing works.

i have read few similar threads and tried to work on a fix but didnt work so far.

this is what i did:

```
  apt-get update 
  apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
  apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
  apt-get install ubuntu-minimal
  apt-get install xorg xserver-xorg
  apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

Im using a Dell Inspiron

Grapics:

Intel HD 4000 /
AMD Radeon 7600M

I write here because I have no idea even in how to identify the problem before trying to solve it. I've been able to access the system in terminal mode only through grub, but I don't know what can I do there if I want to fix what is causing the problem. Any help with this would be much appreciated, thank you all in advance!

Comment: Try changing to console using CTRL-ALT-F3.  If this works, login on console and look for error messages using the 'dmesg' command, or better yet, the 'journalctl -b0 -p4'.  This last command will restrict the output to issues that are likely to be relevant.

Comment: this was one one of the messages: "CRITICAL: Unable to create DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver. Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.screen..."

Comment: Do you think this is something that is causing the problem?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qwZzPVi - i have made a screenshot

Comment: Yes, I do.  After the graphical system freezes, have you tried waiting a few minutes?

Comment: yes i have waited couple of minutes and it did nothing other than the cursor move. cursor can move but it doesnt select or does anything

Comment: Check this bug report:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1736011   Is this the same issue?

Comment: I think i have the exact same bug. do you think its the reason why i get my system freeze? YES!!! EXACT SAME BUG!!!

Comment: i have few other errors as well if you can see in the screenshot that i uploaded in the link above.

Comment: The ACPI problems reported in the top of that screenshort are a problem.  I would try the 'video.allow_duplicates=1' on your kernel command line.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter for instructions on how to try a kernel parameter on boot.

Comment: none of that seemed to work so i have reinstalled 18.04. will see how it goes again